# How to call objects method from list of pointers to objects, which is in a vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I would like to ask how to call objects method (getName and get that name) if my object pointer list is in a vector which is in inner class of my class (this is called inner/nested) to hide private variables and methods. Here is what I wrote so far. I have no idea how to print out all of the objects:

```
   bool Program::checkCategory(string name){
      vector<Category> *ptr = &(impl->categories);
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < ptr->size(); i++){
         cout << ptr->at(i).getName() << endl;
      }
      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Looks fine for me ...

Comment: @g-makulik well, first of all, i get warning here: `i < ptr->size()`. It says "'<' : signed/unsigned mismatch".

Comment: use `size_t` or `unsigned int` to define `i` ...

Comment: You can get rid of that warning by looking up the documentation of `size()`. What does it return?

Comment: @n.m. Cpp documentation: "Returns the number of elements in the vector".

Comment: There's no apparent list of pointers. You have a pointer to a vector. You don't really need a pointer here. You can use a reference, or use the vector directly.,

Comment: @Fractal It's the **type** returned by `size()`, which is in question here! `i` should be of the same or a compatible type.

Comment: You mean, I don't need `vector<Category> *ptr = &(impl->categories);` and I can just use `impl->categories->size();` ?.

Comment: You have to look at the function declaration as well as its description. "Number" is fine and dandy, but what kimd of number? By the way, don't say "cpp" where you mean C++.

Comment: Okay, I will try to figure this out. I think I will learn much more if I will figure this out on my own. Good point, about cpp, its just how I google something for C++. Thanks :)

Comment: Two comments on style: first, it would be much more idiomatic to use iterators, and even perhaps `for_each`, especially if you have C++11 and can use lambdas.  The second is that it is not appropriate to use `std::vector<>::at`.  This function should only be used if out of bounds indexes are an exception event, but not a programming error.

Comment: @JamesKanze thank you for your observations. I will keep them in mind. Unfortunately, for us, university students, there are strict rules of how to write our code and so on. So, write now, I guess I will have to stick with the rules but keep in mind what might be better. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small snippet you included has several problems. By decreasing order of importance:

- You need a semicolon, not comma, before `i++` in the `for` loop.
- If the vector really holds pointers to objects, then you need to call `ptr->at(i)->getName()`, not `ptr->at(i).getName()`. In that case you also (most likely) need to declare the vector as `vector<Category*>`, not `vector<Category>`.
- There is no need to use a pointer to access the vector. If you want a shorter name for the vector, you can use a reference, `vector<Category>& vec = impl->categories`. This makes it clear to the reader that you are only referencing a single vector rather than an array of vectors, and it removes the need to dereference the vector for each method call.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very sorry bout the semicolon, but yer your tip about calling it with -> rather than a dot, really helped me. Its time for a coffee break, I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the full extent of your issue (looks mostly good) but I think you need a semicolon:

You have:

```
i = 0; i < ptr->size(), i++
```

but you need it after size rather than comma:

```
i = 0; i < ptr->size(); i++
```